# What is the right way to send bulk mail with Laravel via AWS SES?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I've SES approved sending rate of 500 emails / second. When I try to send bulk email via Laravel using SES API, the actual mail sending rate is very slow (about ~100 per minute).

Here's an overview of how I do it -

```
...
Users::latest()->chunk(100, function($users) use($newsletter) {

    Notification::send($users, new SendNewsLetter($newsletter));    // queued
})
```

My guess was that I'd send about 100 mails in one shot, however, Horizon shows that the queue which I'm using will have long wait time (of several seconds).

Can someone inform me what is the right way to send bulk emails using SES and Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

> First, i recommand you change the .env file setting for `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` to `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`.

**sending Email action**

```
    $users = Users::latest()->take(100)->get();

    Mail::queue('send', ['users' => $users], function($m) use ($users) {
       foreach ($users as $user) {
          $m->to($user->email)->subject('YOUR SUBJECT GOES HERE');
       }
    });
```

> As next step you need to create a Queue table in the database using
>   the following command before clicking on the route:

```
PHP artisan queue: table
PHP artisan migrate
```

> Before starting the project you need to run a listener to listen to
>   the Queue Request. But you're gonna introduce with the new method as
>   listen is high CPU usage. It's better to use a daemon. So Run the
>   following command:

```
PHP artisan queue:work --daemon --tries=3
```

[Source](https://www.expresstechsoftwares.com/send-bulk-email-using-laravel-queue-feature/)

Comment: `QUEUE_DRIVER` is now `QUEUE_CONNECTION`, which I have set to "redis". I'm using Horizon which works with Redis powered jobs. Wondering if switching over to DB will speed it up.